# Bounding the Google Maps Search area to my Fusion Layer area?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api, google, google-fusion-tables

I have a searchable Google Fusion Layer of Glasgow Postcodes that highlights the searched areas on a map.
The search works fine if I enter a full postcode (for e.g. G1 1BL) that matches the data in the Fusion Table.

However, if I search for just the first part of the postcode to display all the postcodes in the sector ('G1'), instead of highlighting all the areas on my fusion layer with G1, it relocates my map to China where there is a highway named 'G1'.
This isn't the case for all sectors, for example if I search G84 then it highlights the corresponding areas on my map.

This happens with other searches too where unless its a valid postcode I am relocated to the other side of the world to another place with this name as opposed to the fusion layer I am querying.

Is there a way to fix this or will I have to limit the search to only full postcodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Glasgow to the search before entering G1. Search would be for example: "Glasgow G1"

Comment: Would you be able to edit your answer to expand upon it, please?  Anything less than about a paragraph like this gets flagged up for review.